# Overwriting dictionary contents vb.net

Tags: vb.net, service, dictionary, overwrite

I have created a service that updates dictionaries and outputs an xml file of the contents.

It will do it fine first time round, but then i get the following exception when it tries to do it the second time

system.argumentexception an item with the same key has already been added

Is there anyway i can set it so that the dictionary contents are overwritten each time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dictuser(session.SessionId) = New User(session.SessionId, session.UserName)
```

Overwrites the value if the key already exists, adds it to the Dictionary otherwise.